# Simulate mouse scroll using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just to provide context: I want to simulate mouse scroll on Google photos (photos.google.com).

The page contains scroll bar only for a portion of the page (the top "Search" section does not have a scroll bar).

The following does not work (but it works fine for scrolling on say Facebook, or SO):

```
window.scrollTo(0, 10000000)
```

Any clues on how I can simulate mouse scroll ?

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't scrolling the whole window then window.scrollTo is not what you want. You can scroll a section of DOM that has a style of `overflow: scroll` with something like:

```
var scrollBox = document.getElementById('sectionId');
scrollBox.scrollTop = 100; // num pixels from element top you want to scroll down
```

Which is the same as:

```
$('#sectionId').scrollTop(100);
```

You might want to consider a library like https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll which scrolls the screen in an ease-in ease-out fashion, which is easier for users to follow.